# Print table on same page with PHP,HTML and MySQL

Tags: php, html, sql

[I have an options form setup like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phvph.png)

When I press the submit button, I expect to call a function which draws a table from a SQL query

[Table example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8vTZ.png)

Trying to call said function like so:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
if($id > 0) {
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM data WHERE Id = '$id';";
    $sql_res = mysqli_query($d,$sql2) or die("<h1>".mysqli_error()."</h1>");
    tabula($sql_res);
}
?>
```

That results in an error - Undefined index: id

on line

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phvph.png), I can see that you have not specified a `method` attribute for the `form` tag.

The default method for form is GET.

Hence when the form is submitted, you will be getting the value of `id` in `$_GET['id']`

And since there was no `$_POST['id']`, it throwed you the undefined index id error.

Based on this, you can.

1. Change the `method` of the form to `POST`.

**Example**  `<form method="POST">`

2. Fetch the value of the id from the `$_GET` array.

**Example**  `$id = $_GET['id'];`

You can use `$_REQUEST['id']` aswell.

`$_REQUEST`, by default, contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Hope this helps.